# Apache HTTP Server stops working after call on SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, xampp

I'm facing an isssue with XAMPP v.3.2.1 and the Microsoft drivers for SQL Server (`php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` (v.3.2.0.0)). I followed the instructions on how to install these drivers and queries to the SQL Server are answered.

However, with every answer, the Apache module in XAMPP crashes with an APPCRASH on the httpd.exe (v. 2.4.12.0). Unless I close the program, causing the Apache to reboot, the queries won't be answered.

This is the error.log:

```
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:08.413266 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:08.491275 2015] [core:warn] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:09.008546 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:09.815810 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:09.815810 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 20 2015 12:12:41
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:09.815810 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:09.818813 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1903580
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:10.697569 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1903580:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:11.276463 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1903580:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:11.372490 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1903580:tid 384] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:46.469985 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH00428: Parent: child process 1903580 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:47.150020 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:47.221026 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:47.221026 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 20 2015 12:12:41
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:47.221026 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:47.223036 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1902972:tid 512] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1902296
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:48.064078 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1902296:tid 588] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:48.576094 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1902296:tid 588] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Sep 07 15:43:48.646099 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1902296:tid 588] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: what you get from the logs? any error message?

Comment: @paolo Added the error.log

Answer (score 0):

I think to narrow in on the bug you'll have to try to debug the driver dll.
Could you try to get anny messages from the dll using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ?

You also could give http://grantschenck.tripod.com/dbwinv2.htm a try...

Answer (score 0):

I think your PHP version and driver .dll version is mismatching.
Please refer https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 
url and check there is option for which php version which driver require and
after installation you will get "SQLSRV_Readme.htm" file in your ext directory that will help you to configure.